# Ranged attacks in close range

Tags: ranged-attack, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

In D&D, when using a ranged attack within 5 feet of an enemy, you gain disadvantage.

Does Mutants and Masterminds have a similar rule?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Just to be clear, since you tagged the overall tag and the 3E one, do you only want 3E answers, or also the first and second editions?

Answer (score 5):

### No specific rule found

Looking at the tag, assuming 3e is the version in context.

From what I've seen of the rule book and various forums, there isn't an explicit rule for this scenario. (example: https://www.reddit.com/r/mutantsandmasterminds/comments/2yj90n/shooting_into_melee/)

The Hero's Handbook pg 131 explains a section called "Advantages" which do have some perks that affect ranged (ignore cover, etc) and close combat abilities (free attack on successful guard, etc) but there aren't any that cause the two to interact.

Within the Skills section on pg 117, the Close combat skill is described, but no considerations regarding attacking a ranged attacker specifically are found.

Comment: Yup. The answer is very different for 1E (which used more of a d20 setup involving the Point-Blank Shot feat) and 2e (which retained a penalty for shooting into melee), but 3e has simplified that out, as well as not adopting Attack of Opportunity rules.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, under aim it says, "If you’re
making a close attack, or a ranged attack at close range,
you get a +5 circumstance bonus," so it counts as melee

Comment: Can you reference the source and page?

Comment: That's only if you take a Standard action to [Aim](https://www.d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/8-action-adventure/#TOC-AIM-STANDARD-ACTION)

Comment: There are also differences if the target is [Prone](https://www.d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Prone)